# PHP calender with Checkbox: How to populate checkbox from mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a calender with checkboxes for each date. By checking the check boxes users can insert dates into the database. For that I have written some codes which I have shown below and it is working okay. Now, the problem I am facing  is to populate the inserted data in  check boxes when people visit the page. I mean I want to have those check boxes selected if their information is already exist in database otherwise I want those to appear as unchecked. I want to show the data in the same page by which users can insert dates. Would you please kindly help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="show.php">
<?php

$year = "2011";
$month = "8";
$d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1, 2011);

$i=1;
while ($i <= $d) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="<? echo  " $year-$month- " . $i . "";  ?>">
    <? echo  " $year-$month- " . $i . "" . "<br>"; ?>
    <?
    $i++;
}

?>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I would avoid short tags in PHP. Also, double-quoted strings with escaping or HEREDOCs usually work just as well and are easier to read (for humans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nombreChk" value="1"  <?php if ( $record['checked'] >=1) {echo "checked='yes'";}; ?>/>
```